# Getting "ISDEV : error -4006" when trying to build a package using ISCMDBLD.exe

Tags: windows, build, installshield

I am getting below error when trying to build a package using InstallShield 2012 Spring.

```
ISDEV : error -4006: Cannot delete file <path_to_file>\1041.msi
ISDEV : error -4006: Cannot delete file <path_to_file>\1033.msi
ISDEV : fatal error 0:
```

What could be the cause of above error?

Comment: Sounds like the files you listed are in use. Can you delete them? What happens if you run the build as administrator?

Comment: I have tried all - delete/move, rename and even creating another release folder. But none of these solved the problem. i am runningthe build using administrator user only.